# I am trying to create a button that changes its icon and color when clicked in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using font awesome icons and i want to change the button icon and color when clicked for that i have written a directive

```
directive('uiToggleClass', ['$timeout', '$document', function($timeout, $document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AC',
      link: function(scope, el, attr) {
        el.on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var classes = attr.uiToggleClass.split(','),
              targets = (attr.target && attr.target.split(',')) || Array(el),
              key = 0;
          angular.forEach(classes, function( _class ) {
            var target = targets[(targets.length && key)];            
            ( _class.indexOf( '*' ) !== -1 ) && magic(_class, target);
            $( target ).toggleClass(_class);
            key ++;
          });
          $(el).toggleClass('active');

          function magic(_class, target){
            var patt = new RegExp( '\\s' + 
                _class.
                  replace( /\*/g, '[A-Za-z0-9-_]+' ).
                  split( ' ' ).
                  join( '\\s|\\s' ) + 
                '\\s', 'g' );
            var cn = ' ' + $(target)[0].className + ' ';
            while ( patt.test( cn ) ) {
              cn = cn.replace( patt, ' ' );
            }
            $(target)[0].className = $.trim( cn );
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

and my index.html

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-app="plunker">
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ui-toggle-class="btn-success">
          <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload text"></i>
          <span class="text">Upload</span>
          <i class="fa fa-check text-active"></i>
          <span class="text-active">Success</span>
        </button>
    </p>
  </div>
```

But it is not changing the button when clicked can anyone help me? 
Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwd9qg2/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys what i wanted is to change the button when i click on it that means i wanted a new font icon to appear and the color also to be changed for that i have written a ui toggle directive and a bit of css that does the trick 
**

> [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x9j6eeng/)

**

```
.btn-default {
  color: #58666e !important;

}
.btn-success {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: #27c24c;
  border-color: #27c24c;
}
.text-active,
.active > .text,
.active > .auto .text {
  display: none !important;
}

.active > .text-active,
.active > .auto .text-active {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: You can certainly do that with CSS manually, or you could just use `ng-show`, which does exactly the same automatically and makes the HTML easier to understand. See my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle has a bunch of errors (you need to set `"no wrap - in <head>"` for Angular to work.) Also, you have `$` variable that is `undefined` - did you mean to include `jQuery`? You don't have to, for your simple example, and just define it as:

```
var $ = angular.element; // jqLite
```

Here's your working forked [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2df9bvxa/).

But you actually don't need any of this. You can just use the built-in `ng-class` directive:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-success': active}"
        ng-click="active = !active">Toggle</button>
```

**EDIT**:

If you need to change the contents of the button, you can re-use the `active` variable to toggle the displayed content:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-success': active}"
        ng-click="active = !active">

  <i    ng-hide="active" class="fa fa-cloud-upload text"></i>
  <span ng-hide="active" class="text">Upload</span>

  <i    ng-show="active" class="fa fa-check text-active"></i>
  <span ng-show="active" class="text-active">Success</span>

</button>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ne2poq2/)

Comment: what if i just wanted to show only the upload button and when that button is cliked i want to show the success button how do i hide the button untill its clicked?

Comment: "hide the button until it's clicked"? you probably meant "when it's clicked". You can use `ng-show`, for example. There are many ways - each more suitable for a particular scenario than another - to achieve this. I suggest asking a new question - or rather, seeing how similar questions (and there are many of them) were answered